# In go, is it worth avoiding creating slices of size 0?

Tags: go, empty-list

I have a program in which I'm going to make lots and lots of slices, some of which might be empty:

```
nb := something() // something might return 0
slices = append(slices, make([]int, nb))
```

Does `make([]int, 0)` allocates some memory and is, thus, less memory efficient than a `nil` slice although they share the same behavior ? By how much ?

If so, is it worth doing a test to avoid useless allocations, or is the CPU time cost of the test not worth the saving in memory (or any other reason not to do so) ?

```
var sl slice
nb := something()
if nb > 0 {
    sl = make([]int, nb)
}
slices = append(slices, sl)
```

Comment: I'd probably try to measure it.

Comment: Yes but subtle measures tend to be error-prone and I'm afraid the context of my test might have side effects that have nothing to do with the underlying problem I'm dealing with. Plus, I'd rather know *why* what I measure happens rather than just observe it happened.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no difference in the allocated memory between

```
var a []T // nil slice
```

and

```
a := make([]T, 0) // zero-length, zero-capacity, non-nil slice
```

The difference is in the slice header content. In the second case the slice pointer contains some fixed address, same for all 0-sized allocations.

If this code is in a performance critical part of the program, the difference makes ... quite a difference. In the first case you do zero the slice header, in the second case you go through 3-4 function calls, some range checks for cap and length, etc. before malloc returns a pointer to the zero base.

Answer (score 3):

> Does make([]int, 0) allocates some memory

Yes, it allocates a slice header but no backing array. If the slice header doesn't escape the current scope it may be allocated on the stack.

> less memory efficient than a nil slice

In terms of memory used, they're the same.

> is it worth doing a test to avoid useless allocations

In general yes, the 3 or 4 instructions it takes to compare an int are nothing compared to the cycles you'd need to do a memory allocation and initialization.

Comment: @CodingPickle I was careful not to suggest otherwise. Why the down vote?

Comment: First part: fair enough. I'll edit the answer to be explicit about nil. Second part: The Go spec makes no guarantees about stack vs heap. In that sense, an `int` value can perfectly live on the heap. Passing by value or pointer doesn't have anything to do with it either. As OP puts his slice headers onto another slice, they're _most probably_ allocated on the heap. If not, then copied there from the stack. Anyhow these are implementation details.